# SQL C# INSERT with NULL conflicted with FOREIGN KEY where FOREIGN KEY is allowed to be NULL

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

I am constructing an HTML SQL interface and have the option to insert new rows. But when trying to insert a `NULL` into a foreign key value, it tells me

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint...

I specifically made it so the foreign key can accept `NULL` in SQL Server Management Studio.

Below is all the code that is related to inserting the NULL value

```c#
string query = "INSERT INTO [Incident_Table] ([Date_of_Incident],[Incident_Description], [Incident_Type], [At_Fault], [SIF_Exposure],[Status_Category], [Employee_ID], [Injury_ID]) VALUES (@Date_of_Incident, @Incident_Description, @Incident_Type, @At_Fault, @SIF_Exposure, @Status_Category, @Employee_ID, @Injury_ID)";
```

```c#
sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Injury_ID", (TableView.FooterRow.FindControl("txt_Injury_ID_Footer") as TextBox).Text.Trim());
```

```html
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Injury ID" SortExpression="Injury_ID" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="true">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("Injury_ID") %>' runat="server" />
    </ItemTemplate>
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txt_Injury_ID" Text='<%# Eval("Injury_ID") %>' type="number" runat="server" />
    </EditItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txt_Injury_ID_Footer" type="number" runat="server" />
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

I have it check if NULL is passed into the textbox and replace it with `DBNull.Value`

Comment: Empty string <> NULL (even if you [try to coerce it to `int`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=83ce37aad4fa9a7e404b958525919a50))and also please search around for why AddWithValue() is bad.

Comment: Don't use [addwithvalue](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/)

Comment: Try `var txt = (TableView.FooterRow.FindControl("txt_Injury_ID_Footer") as TextBox)?.Text.Trim(); sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@Injury_ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = string.IsNullOrEmpty(txt) ? (object)DBNull.Value : int.Parse(txt);`